# ENOENT on a file that exists. Why?

Tags: linux

```
uprego@udv1320ku12:~$ ls /usr/bin/ -thral | grep java
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 78 Aug 25 2010 javacc
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2.5K Mar 13 2012 dh_nativejava
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Sep 23 19:40 java -> /etc/alternatives/java
...
```

`/usr/bin/java` exists, at least as a reference to something that may exist and be executable.

```
uprego@udv1320ku12:~$ strace /usr/bin/java
execve("/usr/bin/java", ["/usr/bin/java"], [/* 45 vars */]) = 0
...
```

Seems /usr/bin/java resolved correctly to an executable doc.

```
uprego@udv1320ku12:~$ ls /home/uprego/skype-4.0.0.8/ -thral
total 26M
-rw-r--r-- 1 uprego uprego 7.0K Jul 13 10:53 third-party_attributions.txt
drwxr-xr-x 2 uprego uprego 4.0K Jul 13 10:53 sounds
-rw-r--r-- 1 uprego uprego 161 Jul 13 10:53 skype.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 uprego uprego 453 Jul 13 10:53 skype.conf
-rwxr-xr-x 1 uprego uprego 26M Jul 13 10:53 skype
...
```

`/home/uprego/skype-4.0.0.8/skype` exists as a doc, exec permission on.

```
uprego@udv1320ku12:~$ strace /home/uprego/skype-4.0.0.8/skype
execve("/home/uprego/skype-4.0.0.8/skype", ["/home/uprego/skype-4.0.0.8/skype"],
    [/* 45 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
```

Does it really exist?

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: And `file skype` ( in that directory) says what?

Comment: ELF 32-bit LSB..!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `execve()` returns the error ENOENT, it can mean more than one thing:

- the program doesn't exist;
- the program itself exists, but it requires an "interpreter" that doesn't exist.

ELF executables can request to be loaded by another program, in a way very similar to `#!/bin/something` in shell scripts.

Usually, dynamically-linked executables request `/lib/ld-linux.so.2` (or another similar path), which takes care of finding the necessary shared libraries and loading them into memory before the program itself is started.

In this case, I am guessing that you're trying to run a 32-bit Skype on a 64-bit system, and you haven't installed the 32-bit *glibc* and other needed libraries. (On Debian, it should be `libc6:i386`; on Arch, `lib32-glibc`.)

To see the exact path requested by the program, use `readelf -l`:

```
$ readelf -l /bin/sh | grep interpreter
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]

$ readelf -l /tmp/skype-4.1.0.20/skype | grep interpreter
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib/ld-linux.so.2]
```

Comment: Installed the 32 bitted glibc with a `sudo aptitude install libc6-dev-i386` now asks for the 32 bitted libasound2, for which I see no precompiled candidate. Office colleague suggests chrooting. I think I'm trying that and coming back to 32 bit libraries if that does not progress. Thank you.

Comment: @uprego: Try `lib32asound2` or `libasound2:i386`, depending on OS version. Or, actually, just download Skype's `.deb` package...